# Passing dynamic array struct to a function Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I want to create function that accept 'dynamic array struct' and use it to map a data from database *mgodb

```
type Cats struct {
  Meow string 
}
func getCatsPagination() {
   mapStructResult("Animality","Cat_Col", Cats)
}

type Dogs struct {
  Bark string 
}
func getDogsPagination() {
   mapStructResult("Animality","Dog_Col", Dogs)
}

func mapStructResult(db string, collection string, model interface{}) {

   result := []model{} //gets an error here

   err := con.Find(param).Limit(int(limit)).Skip(int(offset)).All(&result) // map any database result to 'any' struct provided

   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }
}
```

and gets an error as "model is not a type", why is it?
any answer will be highly appreciated !

Comment: The error is because `model` is a parameter to function `mapStructResult` not a type.

Comment: You cannot pass types to functions, you must pass values. Only a couple built in functions like `new`, or `make` for example, can accept types as parameters. That is, `model interface{}` can be a **value** of any type, `Dogs` is a **type name**, not a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the ready slice to the `mapStructResult function`.

```
type Cats struct {
    Meow string
}

func getCatsPagination() {
    cats := []Cats{}
    mapStructResult("Animality", "Cat_Col", &cats)
}

type Dogs struct {
    Bark string
}

func getDogsPagination() {
    dogs := []Dogs{}
    mapStructResult("Animality", "Dog_Col", &dogs)
}

func mapStructResult(db string, collection string, model interface{}) {
    err := con.Find(param).Limit(int(limit)).Skip(int(offset)).All(result) // map any database result to 'any' struct provided
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no term in go called dynamic struct. Struct fields are declared before using them and cannot be changed. We can use bson type to handle the data. Bson type is like `map[string]interface{}` used to save the data dynamically.

```
func mapStructResult(db string, collection string, model interface{}) {

   var result []bson.M // bson.M works like map[string]interface{}

   err := con.Find(param).Limit(int(limit)).Skip(int(offset)).All(&result) // map any database result to 'any' struct provided

   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }
}
```

For more information on bson type. Look this godoc for [BSON](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M)